# Prove that there exists $C$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = C$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and there exists $L > 0$ and $ \alpha > 1$ such that for all $x, y$ in $\mathbb R$, $\left | f(x)-f(y) \right | \leq L\left | x-y \right |^{\alpha }$ is true.

Prove that there exists $C$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = C$ for all $x$

If $ \alpha$ was given, I would know how to solve this, but without it, I am lost.

Comment: I think you have a typo in there. It should probably be $\alpha > {\color{red}1}$. See: [Wikipedia::Hölder Continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_continuity)

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Consider $f(x) = x$. Then $|f(x) - (y)| = |x - y| \leq 1 \cdot |x-y|^1$

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer a different question as well. Let's suppose that $\alpha > 1$. In this case, you can show the function is a constant with a three-step argument:

1. Show the function is continuous
2. Show the function is differentiable
3. Show the derivative is $0$

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x_0$. Now for every $x\neq x_0$, we have
$$
\Big|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\Big|\leq L\frac{|x-x_0|^\alpha}{|x-x_0|}=L|x-x_0|^{\alpha-1}.
$$
Since $\alpha -1>0$, the rhs, hence the lhs, tend to $0$ when $x$ tends to $x_0$. By definition of differentiability, this means that 
$$
f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=0.
$$
So $f$ is differentiable with zero derivative on $\mathbb{R}$. By the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), it follows that $f$ is constant, i.e. there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=c$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.